# Json data to output handlebars ember

Tags: ember.js, handlebars.js

I'm trying to output json data with handlebars now everything is working except for the rooms price and i can not seem to find why it's not working.

In the handle bar tutorial there almost trying to do the same stuff

The json data:

```
  [
      {
        "Id": 204448,
        "Name": "Albus Hotel Amsterdam City Centre",
        "ImageUrls": [],
        "Volatility": 0,
        "Address": "Vijzelstraat 49",
        "Rooms": [
          {
            "Id": 0,
            "Name": "Family Suite, 1 King Bed with Sofabed",
            "IsRefundable": false,
            "IsBreakfastIncluded": false,
            "Price": 2437.02,
            "Amenities": []
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
```

The html:

```
   <ul>
      {{#each}}
        <li>
          <div class="hotel_id">{{Id}}</div>
          <div class="hotel_name">{{Name}}</div>
          <div class="hotel_address">{{Address}}</div>
          <div class="hotel_volatility">{{Volatility}}</div>
          <ul>
            {{#each Rooms}}
            <li>
                <div class="room_id">{{Price}}</div>
            </li>
            {{/each}}
          </ul>
        </li>
      {{/each}}
      </ul>
```

Output:

```
204448
Albus Hotel Amsterdam City Centre
Vijzelstraat 49
0
```

Comment: What happens when you output the Name of the Room in the nested loop? Does it output "Family Suite, 1 King Bed with Sofabed"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ember is quite strict with capitalization apparantly: [Nested HandlebarsJS #each helpers with EmberJS not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10306063/nested-handlebarsjs-each-helpers-with-emberjs-not-working). You could write a JSON postprocessor or preprocessor.

Naming conventions in Ember: http://emberjs.com/guides/concepts/naming-conventions/